# How to insert into a table containing list in Cassandra

Tags: go, cassandra, amqp, unmarshalling

How can I insert this JSON (containing list of dishes) into a Cassandra table using Golang?  With my implementation I get an `Unmatched column names/values` error. I suppose the problem is in the unmarshalling part, where I get this Order entity `{1 123 2018-04-09 23:00:00 +0000 UTC [{borsh 1 1} {brokoli 1 2}] cooking}`

```
{
    "user": "1",
    "id": "123",
    "created_at": "2018-04-09T23:00:00Z",
    "dishes": [
        {
            "name": "borsh",
            "menu_id": "1",
            "number": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "brokoli",
            "menu_id": "1",
            "number": 2
        }
    ],
    "status": "cooking"
}
```

**Cassandra tables**

```
create type dish (
    name text, 
    menu_id text, 
    number int
);

create table orders (
    user text, 
    id text, 
    created_at timestamp, 
    dishes list<frozen<dish>>, 
    status text,
    primary key(id)
);
```

**Orders structure and Insert query implementation**

```
type Order struct {
    User      string    `json:"user"`
    Id        string    `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    Dishes    []Dish    `json:"dishes"`
    Status    string    `json:"status"` //pending OR completed
}

type Dish struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    MenuId string `json:"menu_id"`
    Number int    `json:"number"`
}

func saveOrder(mes amqp.Message) error{
    var order foodDomain.Order
    if err := json.Unmarshal(mes.Body, &order); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cassandraConn, err := GetCassandraConnection()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := cassandraConn.Query("INSERT INTO orders(id, created_at, dishes, status, user) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
        order.Id, order.CreatedAt, order.Dishes, order.Status, order.User).Exec(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while inserting Emp")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully added order to cassandra")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Your `VALUES` section should include 5 question marks, but only includes 4.

Comment: @John, this is the solution. Thank you so much!